# Do I need to bring the laboratory back to Kerbin?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The [related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143348/do-i-need-to-bring-my-scientific-instruments-back-from-the-mun) talks about bringing experiments back from space. This can be done without penalties if a scientist "removes" the data from given device and stores it in a command module, then returns the module back home (leaving the "experiments" in space).

Can I do the same thing with a laboratory? I understand the laboratory can repeat given experiment within a biome multiple times (for rapidly diminishing returns) and the command module can only store one result per biome, so I won't get the repeated experiments, but will there be any other penalties if I leave the lab on Minmus and return the data through command modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning data via antenna is the *only* way to get science out of a laboratory.

With a laboratory, you can create *research data* from experiment reports on the same vessel. The laboratory then gradually converts that data to science. That science then needs to be transmitted to Kerbin via antenna. Recovering the laboratory means that you lose any science it has stored.

The data processing is independent from whatever else happens with the research report. After you got stored the data from the report in the science lab, you can do whatever you want with it, it won't affect the operation of the lab in any way.